# What is this symbol for?

Tags: schematics, symbol, diagram

[image]

It looks like a connector, or as the diagram is about a dynamo, a light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely a connector, slight resemblance to IEC standard plug and socket symbol. Likely drawn in the circuit to make it clearer the separation between source and load.

Comment: When I search for *IEC standard plug and socket symbol* symbols very similar shows up. Thanks!